# “provide” vs. “provide for”

Tags: difference, legalese

What are the similarities and differences? In the example below, what would be the difference between using “provide for” and (just) “provide”?

> 1. **provide:** Make available for use; supply
>
> **provide for:** Make adequate preparation for (a possible event)
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries, Definition of “provide”](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/provide?q=PROVIDE+for#provide__11)</sub>

> It turns out that there are contractual answers as
>   well: creditors can **provide for** these possibilities in advance, not between
>   themselves but by taking security interests in your assets—in other words,
>   a right to take back your property directly if you run out of money.
> <sub>Source: p 107, The Legal Analyst, Ward Farnsworth</sub>

Comment: "creditors can enable the use of these possibilities" but do not provide the possibilities, for example the government provides

Comment: I think no one can *provide* possibilities! :)

Comment: I have edited your question to refer to the definition of “provide for” that your example uses, but this may have been the main source of your confusion so I will comment here as well. Despite the general context of law, this use does not follow the format of definition 2.2. That is a specialized use which states that a law _contains provisions_ (specifies methods and/or funding) intended to achieve a specified effect. In your example, “provides for” is used in its usual way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your quote, the meaning of *provide for* is *to act to prepare for something* (Wiktionary, [verb sense 2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/provide)).

We may rephrase the quotation this way:

> It turns out that there are contractual answers as well: creditors can **prepare for** these possibilities in advance, not between themselves but by taking security interests in your assets—in other words, a right to take back your property directly if you run out of money.

Let's look at an example sentence:

> The architect **provided for** (= *prepared for*) the possibility of storms by strengthening the abutments.

If you substitute **provide** in the place of **provide for**:

> The architect **provided** the possibility of storms by strengthening the abutments.

the resulting sentence is absurd: stronger abutments are somehow supposed to invoke storms.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR -

> A subject [noun] "provides" some thing or purpose [direct object, also a noun].

But

> You "provide for" a target/purpose/circumstance [indirect object].
>
> You "provide [a perhaps implied/unspecified noun] for" a [perhaps conditional, future, or abstract] target/purpose/circumstance.

Long Version:

When you "provide" something, the [noun] being provided is the subject of the sentence, and the result/outcome is the direct object. X provides Y. Ask: "What does the thing provide?"

> **A house** provides shelter.
>
> (S)**A house** (V)provides (D.O)shelter.
>
> **My job** provides [me with] income.
>
> **This answer** might (not?) provide clarity :)

"Providing for" something indicates the purpose or desired outcome, with the "what/how" for reaching that outcome perhaps implied or omitted.

The desired outcome or target receives the action, and is the object of the preposition "for," making it the *indirect* object. Ask: "For whom is the man's job providing?" For his family.

There could be a 2nd ("modal"?) verb in addition to "to provide/providing."

> His job provides [income & other implied comforts] **for his family**.
>
> His job allows him to provide [income & other implied comforts] **for his family**.
>
> The contract provides [safeguards] **for these circumstances**.
>
> The contract must provide [safeguards] **for these circumstances**.
>
> A reason given in the U.S. Constitution for establishing the country is to "provide [a military] **for the common defense.**"

Aside from all this, you also have "provided that..." as a conditional, where what follows describes what must happen in order for the stated outcome to occur.

> You will get that raise, provided that you win us this contract.